# Selenium webdriver opens url but then gives timeout exception

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am working with selenium in python 3.7.4
My code is

```
from selenium import webdriver
url='https://www.google.com/'
driver_exe='C\Users\admin\.spyder-py3\IEDriverServer.exe
driver=webdriver.Ie(driver_exe)
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.get(url)
driver.quit()
```

I run this code then it opens a blank goolge webpage Then I get the error message TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for page to load.

Can anyone explain what is going on here

Comment: Is your driver updated to latest? Is the browser updated to latest? If you navigate to the URL manually whereever you are running this script, does it load?

Comment: I am using internet explorer but yes it is all up to date. Not sure what you mean by navigating to the URL manually but when I run the script it opens a brand new webpage that loads the URL in my core

Comment: I mean go onto the machine where this script is running (your desktop or VM or wherever), launch the browser, and navigate to the URL. If you are running this script on some VM or some build machine that doesn't have access to the internet, etc. then the page not load for that reason instead of some code/config reason.

Comment: The code correctly navigates to the URL. It opens google.com homepage and i can interact with it.